# Cannot get AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials AccessToken for Azure Mobile Service

Tags: sharepoint, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

I have been following the Azure Mobile Services tutorial ([here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-calling-sharepoint-on-behalf-of-user/)) and am having trouble getting my authentication process to work correctly.

I can get my phone application to login correctly, and it appears that the fields are set correctly, however when I get the AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials the AccessToken is null.

The code I am using to get access to Sharepoint is:

```
    var identities = await user.GetIdentitiesAsync();
    AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials creds = identities.OfType<AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials>().FirstOrDefault();
    return creds == null ? null : new SharepointContext(creds.AccessToken, settings);
```

As the AccessToken is null I cannot create the UserAssertion lower down in the example code, so my service returns a 500 error all the time. The exception generated is:

```
Exception=System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: assertion
```

The code that generates the exception looks like this:

```
    AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    AuthenticationResult ar = ac.AcquireToken(sharepointURL, new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), new UserAssertion(userToken));
```

I can successfully load data from the table API, so I am confident that my mobile service is correctly configured.

The code I am using to access the Mobile Service is:

```
JToken result = await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync("contacts", HttpMethod.Get, new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

Has anybody had any success getting this to work?

Comment: have you ever solved this?

Comment: AccessToken is null for me too. If you have an answer, please share with us.

Comment: I changed over to use a different API as I couldn't get this working from memory.